# How to add Support for Css Modules and Sass in Create React App rendered on the Server SSR

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am using [this](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/universal-react) Repo to work with React SSR using Create React APP, But when running the code 
The styles never seems to get applied to the code when i run the same page via client npm start it works without any problem with all styles embedded but when running via server the Styles dosent seem to get applied.

Do i Need to eject the Webpack config / is there any way i tried using isomorphic-style-loader but it didnt work out. Any steps will be helpful

Using this Repo as it is very basic .

Answer (score 0):

If you look into bootstrap.js file you'll see a require call to "ignore-styles". Because of this every style import will be ignored. Else you would need a babel plugin like "babel-plugin-transform-assets" or better a webpack configuration for the server code to handle the assets. SSR is not trivial and that's why there are frameworks like https://nextjs.org/ that handle all this stuff. Give it a try, it's very easy to setup.

Comment: I want to be able to do this ground up. And not use my frameworks for my sake of understanding. What could be the next steps to get this working in a shape

Comment: Then why you use CRA? Ground up would mean that you write your own Webpack config. So you can use it for client- and serverside. It's not that hard..

Comment: i can still eject the create react app and do the changes , just i didnt want to start from stratch , any suggestions